# Remove image upload button in Microsoft BotFramework iFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, botframework

Does the iframe embed has any configuration / support to disable the button ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embed web chat doesn't have direct configuration to disable the upload botton and functions. However, the embed web chat is built by the project [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), so you can modify the source code, and compile into your own version to achieve your requirement.

1. Clone the repo https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat to your local work space, run `npm install` to install all the node.js dependencies.
2. Comment the code section from line 114 to 132 at [/src/Shell.tsx](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Shell.tsx#L114).
3. run `npm run build` to compile the source code to javascript file.
4. follow [Easy: In your non-React website, run Web Chat inline](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline) section leverage your own js file in your website.

Comment: Is there any new alternative to this answer?