# Remove the Image upload button in MS-bot framework

Tags: css, sass, botframework

I want to remove the image upload button in MS-botframwork. I am making changes in botchat.scss file and then running npm run prepublish but nothing is happening. I don't want to make changes in the botchat.css file. Can you tell me exactly what I have to do.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove image upload button in Microsoft BotFramework iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615560/remove-image-upload-button-in-microsoft-botframework-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the webchat is created dynamically using React, the code is placed in the `botchat.js` file. You have to comment or delete the following lines in the file `botchat.js`:

```
React.createElement("label", { className: "wc-upload", onKeyPress: function (evt) { return _this.handleUploadButtonKeyPress(evt); }, tabIndex: 0 },
React.createElement("svg", null,
React.createElement("path", { d: "M19.96 4.79m-2 0a2 2 0 0 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0zM8.32 4.19L2.5 15.53 22.45 15.53 17.46 8.56 14.42 11.18 8.32 4.19ZM1.04 1L1.04 17 24.96 17 24.96 1 1.04 1ZM1.03 0L24.96 0C25.54 0 26 0.45 26 0.99L26 17.01C26 17.55 25.53 18 24.96 18L1.03 18C0.46 18 0 17.55 0 17.01L0 0.99C0 0.45 0.47 0 1.03 0Z" })),
React.createElement("input", { id: "wc-upload-input", tabIndex: -1, type: "file", ref: function (input) { return _this.fileInput = input; }, multiple: true, onChange: function () { return _this.onChangeFile(); }, "aria-label": this.props.strings.uploadFile, role: "button" })),
```

Those lines render and display the image-upload-button, uncomment the lines to display the button again.

Answer (score 1):

The embed web chat doesn't have direct configuration to disable the upload botton and functions. However, the embed web chat is built by the project [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), so you can modify the source code, and compile into your own version to achieve your requirement.

1. Clone the repo https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat to your local work space, run `npm install` to install all the node.js dependencies.
2. Comment the code section from line 114 to 132 at [/src/Shell.tsx](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Shell.tsx#L114).
3. run `npm run build` to compile the source code to javascript file.
4. follow [Easy: In your non-React website, run Web Chat inline](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline) section leverage your own js file in your website.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by changing **CSS**.

Do not change the `botchat.css` because it will be overwritten on the net build.

You have to do the changes in `botchat.scss` and after that rebuild CSS: `npm run build-css`

```
.wc-upload {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            display: none; // add this to hide image for upload

            svg {
                height: 18px;
                width: 26px;
            }
        }

&.has-upload-button .wc-textbox {
            left: 15px; // change the value from 48px to 15px to move to left input control
        }
```

Comment: If one is hosting the page as Script on the page as opposed to hosting as iFrame, one can add these CSS to the web page itself. There won't be any need to rebuild botchat.css.